Are Type 1 errors associated with model accuracy for linear models
It is at the least uncommon for discussion of statistical significance of predictors to mention model accuracy. However, my intuition is that I would be more comfortable believing in the importance of individual predictors from a more accurate model (potentially train error but ideally some error on a holdout set) than a less accurate model.
As a first gesture, perhaps high error could indicate that the functional form of some linear model is not correct, or that we are missing important predictors.
Is there any literature or prior discussion about relating type 1 errors when examining coefficient significance to model accuracy?

"All models are wrong, some models are useful". It is not strictly necessary for a model to be an oracle model to obtain valid inference. Conversely, a type 1 error does not imply that the model is inaccurate - it could in fact be bad luck which, conditional on the error having occured, is much greater than 0.05 probability due to Bayes rule.

One relationship jumps out immediately. The residual variance plays into all of the coefficient standard errors and t-stat calculations.
Residual variance is related to the square loss, that is, the model performance.
All else equal, the larger the residual variance, the harder it is to get a small test p-value and narrow confidence intervals. This seems to directly relate to type I errors.

When you mention performance on a holdout set, however, you allude to doing some kind of model tuning to get the preferred model (feature selection, hyperparameter tuning, whatever). After you take such steps, however, the downstream inferences are distorted, possibly grossly.

Thanks for the response. I'm not imagining a model tuning process here for the reasons you mention. Just as a way to assess whether one model (the one we have specified prior to examination of any coefficient or overall error) is a good one.
I was hoping to anticipate a critique about training error being assumed to generalize, which was the motivation for mentioning error on a holdout set specifically. Point well taken

It seems to me that a similar problem could occur when optimizing on train error. For example, I might fit a model, see poor performance on the input data on which the model was trained, and decide that I need an interaction term. In this process, I am essentially hunting for lower error, thereby reducing residual variance. So in effect, this would be trying many model combinations until I reach one that is more likely to produce statistically significant coefficients, in virtue of having lower residual variance?

@Jonah That's related to, if not a form of, forward stepwise regression, the issues with which have been discussed many times on here. Yes, you are distorting downstream inferences when you make decisions based on the (random) data, possibly distorting mildly, possibly distorting grossly.

"Statistical significance" has a very particular meaning. It doesn't quantify the likelihood of type 1 error in general but only a very particular source of potential error: the error associated with generalizing from a random sample to the population the sample was drawn from.
If a coefficient from a model is statistically significant at the 99% confidence level, that tells us that we can be pretty "confident" that our finding that the coefficient is not zero is not just an artifact of sampling error. But the coefficient estimate could be "wrong" for all sorts of other reasons: model misspecification, e.g. omitted variable bias, incorrect functional form, measurement error, or even sample bias (statistical significance only measures the error associated with generalizing from a random, unbiased sample). Those are all potential sources of Type 1 error, and should be a absolutely critical component to whether or not you believe the results of any given model. But they but are totally separate from the concept of "statistical significance," which is why they are not usually discussed in the context of statistical significance.
